# What is the best way to archive SQL query results?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have a 500 million row SQL query result from one table, I want to archive this on my local PC before deleting it.

How can I do that in the fastest and best way?

I checked from client statistics, bytes received from server is 5 GB.

In case of something going bad, I will reupload this SQL data into the table it came from.

The reason I do is, I want to empty space for my SQL Server.

Comment: Create a new database, use `select.. into.. database.dbo.table` then backup database.

Comment: You can try using [BCP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility). "The **bulk copy program** utility (bcp) bulk copies data between an instance of Microsoft SQL Server and a data file in a user-specified format."

Comment: What's the consideration here? Is it purely space on the server, or is performance an issue and that is why you'd want to keep the table smaller? 5 GB really isn't that much when it comes to nowadays storage space. How often are you supposed to access/query the data, or restore it back for reporting? I'd consider partitioning before extracting/deleting the data if the frequency of accessing is regular.

Comment: FYI, if by *"I want to empty space for my SQL."* you mean you want to free up space on the hard disk, deleting data won't do that. When the amount of data in the database gets smaller the actual file does not, instead the database has "internal" free space, which it will use before the file grows.

Comment: @Larnu yes I meant that.  I will seach for that Internal Space thing, I didnt know it.

Comment: @SchmitzIT It's for purely space, and for azure 5 gb is a still thing. Getting rid of 5 gb will help. The 5 5GB data will not be used ever, I wan't to archieve for backup in case of something happens.

Comment: If you will delete old records periodically, for example, older 3 years, so you can use partition table technologies to do this automatically. You have a problem with free spaces, so you can create a partition table in a new filegroup which will be stored in additional storage. The second way, you can do this manually, so to do this you can create an archive table in a new filegroup which will be stored in additional storage and then Insert into this table all records which you want to delete